# Why does my usage of Perl's DBI->connect fail silently?

Tags: perl, dbi

Why does this code fail silently? How do I get it to show me exactly what the SQL error is?

```
$dbh=DBI->connect($db_name,$db_user,$db_pass);
```

I modified the code to look like this:

```
$dbh=DBI->connect($db_name,$db_user,$db_pass)
    or die("could not connect to db: $db_name");
```

Which instead of allowing me to use `$dbh` unassigned, it will fail as expected, but it does not tell me exactly why it's failing. The values of `$db_name` etc, are all set with valid values as far as I can see.

I know the real error (the MySQL server is actually not running) but for future reference, I'd like to see the true error in case I am causing an auth failure for example.

Comment: Again, please show us complete scripts (although masking the username and password!). The answers to your last several questions have related to stuff you haven't shown.

Comment: @brian I'm sorry. I will not make this mistake again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not seeing why the `connect` fails because you aren't doing what the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI) show you to do. The error will be in the `$DBI::errstr` variable:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password)
     or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Ensure you read the documentation for any functions or methods that you want to use. :)

Comment: Okie dokes, I will use this from now on.

Comment: I now see your own answer. I suspect you discovered it at the same time I was writing it because I think you submitted your answer slightly before mine. Don't feel bad about accepting your answer if its the right one (not that I'm complaining) :)

Answer (score 2):

Aha, the error is stored in `$DBI::errstr`, so I can modify my code like so:

```
$dbh=DBI->connect($db_name,$db_user,$db_pass)
    or die("could not connect to db: $DBI::errstr");
```

According to the documentation, it fails silently by design.

Comment: @brian Ah, of course. How silly of me, I should always re-read the documentation to make sure I don't miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

Pass RaiseError => 1 as an option when connecting, then your script will die on errors. My Perl shop has a standard configuration of:

```
{
  RaiseError => 1,
  PrintError => 0,
  AutoCommit => 1,
  mysql_auto_reconnect => 1,
}
```

Comment: Nice. How do I set a standard configuration?

Comment: There might be an official way; you could subclass DBI and override the connect method. Our projects have their own specialised DBH-dispensing modules that load configuration from YAML.

Comment: I also hide the DBI stuff behind application level code. If you decide to switch to RoseDB or something else later, the application level code stays the same although the implementation differs. Whether it's subclasses or delegation, it's still hiding the details so your application is loosely coupled to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my usage of [rjh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037339/why-does-my-usage-of-perls-dbi-connect-fail-silently/2037395#2037395). I think I prefer this over the `die` approach, but not sure yet...

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password, { RaiseError => 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of 'or' is a syntax error. The listed code should not run at all.

You want:

```
$dbh=DBI->connect($db_name,$db_user,$db_pass) 
    or die("could not connect to db: $db_name");
```

Note that `or die...` is part of the original statement, not a new statement.

Comment: Oops, typo. Well spotted. I've corrected this now. But maybe your answer should have been a comment?

Comment: Don't type in code. Cut and paste the actual code that you are using. I've mentioned this a few times already, but you're sorta abusing people's time to answer the problem you present, like the syntax error, rather than showing the actual code you are using. You can get better answers and ease the burden on the people giving you free help, so please do so. :)

Comment: @brian Yes you're totally right, I'm so sorry to have wasted your time; I can only imagine how much you hate nagging me about this. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try including the value of $! in your die message.

```
$dbh = DBI->connect($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass)
  or die("could not connect to db ($db_name): $!");
```

See [$! in perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OS_ERROR).

Comment: That won't help, as DBI does not set `$!`. See documentation: "If the connect fails (see below), it returns `undef` and sets both `$DBI::err` and `$DBI::errstr`. (It does _not_ explicitly set `$!`.)"